# HDFS Command Line Append

Tags: shell, command-line, hadoop, append, hdfs

Is there any way to append to a file on HDFS from command line like copying file:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal <localsrc> URI
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is implemented in Hadoop 2.3.0 as [appendToFile](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#appendToFile) with a syntax like:

```
hdfs dfs -appendToFile localfile /user/hadoop/hadoopfile
```

(it was first suggested in 2009 when the HDFS Append feature was being contemplated: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6239 )

Answer (score 1):

cli doesn't support append, but httpfs and fuse both has support for appending files.

```
w301% ls -lA
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 hdfs supergroup 0 Nov 14 01:02 test.me
w301% cat test.me
w301% sync
w301% cat test.me
hello
w301% echo "more rows" >> test.me
w301% sync
w301% cat test.me 
hello
more rows
```

EDIT: but keep in mind, that only one client can append to file.

Comment: Do you know any reference to clear instructions to set up httpfs or fuse and try out append, I tried httpfs, but I failed.

Comment: i meant httpfs in hdfs 2.0 http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WebHDFS.html#Append_to_a_File

Comment: in case of fuse, you simply open file with append flag (as usual in you favorite language or use >> in shell) and write to file. recent fuse should correctly handle this flag