# Append hdfs file to local file?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Since I can use `hdfs dfs -appendToFile <localFile> ... <hdfsFile>` command to append local file to hdfs files as mentioned in [HDFS Command Line Append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365604/hdfs-command-line-append).
Are there any similar commands that allow me to **append** files in the opposite direction? That is, append  hdfs files to certain local file.
For example, some commands like

```
# append files to local
hdfs dfs -appendToLocal <hdfsFile> <localFile>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that `hdfs dfs -getmerge` solves my question.

```
hdfs dfs -getmerge -nl <hdfsFile1> <hdfsFile2> ... <hdfsFileN>  <localFile>
```